# PDO exception on php artisan clear-compiled in Laravel 5

Tags: exception, pdo, composer-php, laravel-5.1, forge

I am facing a weird issue with forge . I have a laravel5 app hosted on a DO Server and I use Forge as well. When I try to deploy the script after I pushed new commits , I keep getting :

```
> php artisan clear-compiled

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'troisdemis_com.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)
```

I restarted the Server , uninstalled the repo, dropped the database ( ssh) reinstalled the repo again , and whenever I run composer install I still keep the same error.
Do you know guys what could cause the issue ?

Comment: as far as i am aware, clear-compiled should only fiddle with php files (and temporaries, like one in storage directory). perhaps check things in this order might help: database --> migrations (if you use it) --> models. i wonder if anything triggered during cleanup.

Comment: Stupid question but you do have the permissions table in your db?